# Laravel $request->getContent() returns empty string

Tags: laravel

I'm posting a CSV file from one Laravel app to another:

Sending:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($filePath);
Log::debug('contents', ['contents'=>$contents]); // I can see contents of file
Http::withToken($token)->attach('attachment', $contents)->post($uri);
```

Receiving:

```
$content = $request->getContent();
Log::debug('about to store content to file...', ['content'=>$content]);

// about to store content to file... {"content":""}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: wich route file is `$uri` gonna use ? maybe you have a protocol redirect or another type of redirect wich will empty the request ?

Comment: Thank you. I don’t believe I have any redirects happening. But I will check. Are you saying if it goes from http to https, the attachment would be lost?

Comment: yop, exactly. the redirect from http to https would lose the body of the content (it depends on many things it not to happen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files are not the content, you should fetch the file out with.

```
$request->file('attachment');
```

If you want to send a file as a raw request body, this snippet shows you how from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client).

```
$response = Http::withBody(
    file_get_contents($filePath), 'text'
)->post($uri);
```

Comment: Thank you for the kind response. That makes sense. The “receiving” app was previously set up this way and already receives files from other sources with the above code. So, I will check out the link you provided and try to match the same format.